# How to get rid of "string index out of range" error when trying to replace multiple occurrences from lists?

Tags: python

I am doing this for a project for which I need to do some web-scraping from Wikipedia specifically. Something that was working before has suddenly stopped working now. It needed to tell me the profession of the person that the User entered from the Wikipedia Article and the method I was using was this:

```
#Finding their profession
#Declaring keywords for each profession
sportspersonKeywords = ['Sportsperson', 'Sportsman', 'Sportsman', 'Sports', 'Sport', 'Coach', 'Game', 'Olympics', 'Paralympics', 'Medal', 'Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Player', 'sportsperson', 'sportsman', 'sportsman', 'sports', 'sport', 'coach', 'game', 'olympics', 'paralympics', 'medal', 'bronze', 'silver', 'gold', 'player', 'footballer', 'Footballer']

scientistKeywords = ['Scientist', 'Mathematician', 'Chemistry', 'Biology', 'Physics', 'Nobel Prize', 'Invention', 'Discovery', 'Invented', 'Discovered', 'science', 'scientist', 'mathematician', 'chemistry', 'biology', 'physics', 'nobel prize', 'invention', 'discovery', 'invented', 'discovered', 'science', 'Physicist', 'physicist', 'chemist', 'Chemist', 'Biologist', 'biologist']

politicianKeywords = ['Politician', 'Politics', 'Election', 'President', 'Vice-President', 'Vice President', 'Senate', 'Senator', 'Representative', 'Democracy', 'politician', 'politics', 'election', 'president', 'vice-president', 'vice president', 'senate', 'senator', 'representative', 'democracy']

#Declaring the first sentence (from the summary)
firstSentence = summary.split('.')[0]

profession = ['Scientist', 'Sportsperson', 'Politician']
professionFinal = ''

#Splitting the first sentence of the summary into separate words
firstSentenceList = firstSentence.split()

#Replacing each other character in the first sentence
counter = 0
print(firstSentenceList)
for i in firstSentenceList:
  x = [',', '.']
  if x[0] in i:
    firstSentenceList = firstSentenceList[counter].replace(',', '')
    counter += 1
  elif x[1] in i:
    i = i.replace('.', '')
    counter += 1
  else:
    counter += 1
    continue
print(firstSentenceList)

#Checking each word in the first sentence against the keywords in each profession to try to get a match
for i in firstSentenceList:
  if i in sportspersonKeywords:
    professionFinal = profession[1]
    break
  elif i in scientistKeywords:
    professionFinal = profession[0]
    break
  elif i in politicianKeywords:
    professionFinal = profession[2]
    break

#if a match is found, then that person has that profession, if not, then their profession is not in our parameters
if professionFinal == '':
  print('[PROFESSION]: NOT A SPORTPERSON, SCIENTIST, OR POLITICIAN')
else:
  print('[PROFESSION]: ' + professionFinal)
```

This was all going great for people like Albert Einstein and Serena Williams and Donald Trump and others, but when I searched for [James Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Watson). Just to clarify, I only needed to find their profession from the parameters above. If they weren't a scientist, sportsperson, or politician, no need to go any further, just say they were neither. Unfortunately I am using Repl.it, which does not allow for breakpoints and many other things, so I had to manually debug by putting in the `print()` statements to check how everything was working out. I discovered when I printed the **`firstSentenceList`** variable storing my first sentence (the one I'm using to check for keywords) that it should've recognized biologist, but it didn't because the word biologist was being followed by a comma; so it was listed like this: ***`'biologist,'`***, which messed up the keywords search. This code:

```
#Replacing each other character in the first sentence
counter = 0
print(firstSentenceList)
for i in firstSentenceList:
  x = [',', '.']
  if x[0] in i:
    firstSentenceList = firstSentenceList[counter].replace(',', '')
    counter += 1
  elif x[1] in i:
    i = i.replace('.', '')
    counter += 1
  else:
    counter += 1
    continue
print(firstSentenceList)
```

is something that I have just put in to try to replace the things like commas and full stops in the list.  I tried to run it and wallah, errors. One of which was this:

[image: Error message 1 - "string index out of range"]

So, in short, I don't know how to replace the aforementioned items from each string in the list. Could anyone please teach me how to do it. Again, for anyone who has seen my other post and wowed at how I manage to make them this long, sorry about that.

**Link to my Repl.it: [Wikipedia Web-scraping Project - Brightbulb123 - Repl.it](https://repl.it/@BrightBulb123/WikiPedia-Web-scraping-Project-Coding-Competition#main.py)

Comment: I think that a regex would fit better...
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
firstSentenceList = firstSentenceList[counter].replace(',', '')
```

In `replace(',','')`, you need to mention the space like `.replace(',',' ')`

One suggestion would be to convert the firstSentenceList into dictionary. It would be simpler by keys and values pair to solve the problem of multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the following line:

```
    firstSentenceList = firstSentenceList[counter].replace(',', '')
```

Here you are assigning the word at position `counter` to list. Effectively replacing list with single word. This will fix the problem:

```
    firstSentenceList[counter] = firstSentenceList[counter].replace(',', '')
```

Same goes for `.` (`X[1]`) as well.

A better approach will be to remove `,` and `.` when you are iterating over the list in this block:

```
for i in firstSentenceList:
    if i in sportspersonKeywords:
        professionFinal = profession[1]
        break
```

Like:

```
for i in firstSentenceList:
    i = i.replace(',', '').replace('.', '')
    if i in sportspersonKeywords:
        professionFinal = profession[1]
        break
```